# Ломается кирилица в редакторе Visual Studio

Tags: visual-c++

Изначально проблема состояла в том, что при отладке кода в консоли вместо русскоязычных символов выводились ???. Решил ее путем сохранения файла в кодировке 1251, но в таком случае, после закрытия файла в Visual Studio 2019, весь русскоязычный текст в файле меняется на êëàâèàòóðå ìîáèëüíîãî, но при отладке в консоле все равно был русский язык. В самой консоле стоит шрифт Lucida Console

Помогите грамотно решить эту проблему

Данный код присутсвтует в начале main()

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
```

Comment: Какая ОС на хосте?

Comment: @Sheridan Win 10 x64

Comment: Попробуйте с другой стороны зайти (и я думаю что этот путь предпочтительнее): https://stackoverflow.com/a/388500/1597497

Comment: @Sheridan у меня изначально стояла данная кодировка и данный шрифт. В итоге в консоле были ??? вместо русс. Сейчас еще заметил, что у меня сохраняется в 1252, хотя сохранял в 1251

Comment: А исходник в какой кодировке?

Comment: @Sheridan изначально код писался в 65001 UTF-8. Потом пересохранил в 1251